# Why is std::inner_product slower than the naive implementation?

Tags: c++, floating-point, sse, numeric, fast-math

This is my naive implementation of dot product:

```
float simple_dot(int N, float *A, float *B) {
    float dot = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    dot += A[i] * B[i];
    }

    return dot;
}
```

And this is using the C++ library:

```
float library_dot(int N, float *A, float *B) {
    return std::inner_product(A, A+N, B, 0);
}
```

I ran some benchmark(code is here https://github.com/ijklr/sse), and the library version is a lot slower. 
My compiler flag is `-Ofast -march=native`

Comment: Use `0.0f` as the initial value.

Comment: What happens if you change 0 to 0f in the call to inner_product?

Comment: You should be able to look at the library implementation as it's a template.

Comment: I will try it now.

Comment: @NathanOliver: A compiler error because `f` is not a valid octal digit.

Comment: Did you even compare if your two algorithms produce the same result for non-trivial inputs?

Comment: wow. I re-ran my test and that 0.0f changed everything.

➜  sse git:(master) ✗ ./dot-product       
Generating 33554432 element vectors.
             simple_dot 0.0186736
            library_dot 0.018313
    simple_prefetch_dot 0.0499649
             unroll_dot 0.0223053
                sse_dot 0.0189242
                avx_dot 0.0181958
         avx_unroll_dot 0.0183683
avx_unroll_prefetch_dot 0.0184743

Comment: @KerrekSB  is it because it had to do the int conversion everytime?

Comment: this is the benchmark before:
Generating 33554432 element vectors.
             simple_dot 0.0185088
            library_dot 0.12566
    simple_prefetch_dot 0.0496267
             unroll_dot 0.0227776
                sse_dot 0.0191732
                avx_dot 0.0184244
         avx_unroll_dot 0.018839
avx_unroll_prefetch_dot 0.0190001

Comment: @ijklr: Yes, indeed. See the machine code I posted in my link.

Comment: You should know though, that neither the naive version nor the updated use of `inner_product` actually result in good code (with GCC and `-O3 -march=native -ffast-math`). GCC gives it a decent try and manages to use `vfmadd231ps`, but it does it with only one accumulator which means the loop is still limited by FMA *latency* instead of throughput. Even ICC does not unroll enough. Clang gets the `inner_product` right, but doesn't unroll the naive loop enough. Using intrinsics you can fix it on all compilers.

Comment: Did you try using `std::transform_reduce` instead? You could even using the nonseq execution policy to vectorize it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your two functions don't do the same thing. The algorithm uses an accumulator whose type is *deduced* from the initial value, which in your case (`0`) is `int`. Accumulating floats into an int does not just take longer than accumulating into a float, but also produces a different result.

The equivalent of your raw loop code is to use the initial value `0.0f`, or equivalently `float{}`.

(Note that `std::accumulate` is a very similar in this regard.)

Comment: Thanks. this helps!

Comment: GCC does not unroll the loop and `-funroll-loops` does not break the dependency chain. Clang unrolls 4 times which is great. So at least with GCC `std::inner_product` is not optimal i.e. you have to optimize by hand anyway with reductions.